# Choosing parameters for SAGA Wetness Index?

Tags: saga, hydrology, parameters, topographic-wetness-index

I've been working with SAGA GIS to calculate the Topographic Wetness Index of an alpine catchment. I am using the tool `Terrain analysis > Hydrology > SAGA Wetness Index` because, compared to `Terrain analysis > Hydrology > Topographic Wetness Index (TWI)`, the output is not a one-pixel wide film but a (to me) more realistic broader network of streams.

My input is a DEM (with sinks filled) that was derived from airborne LiDAR data and has a resolution of 1x1m. I don't have a *Weights* raster which is an optional input. Now my problem is that there are six parameters that shall be chosen before the calculation:

- Suction (default = 10)
- Type of Area (default = *square root of catchment area*; other options *total catchment area* or *specific catchment area*)
- Type of Slope (default = *catchment slope*, other option *local slope*)
- Minimum Slope (default = 0)
- Offset Slope (default = 0.1)
- Slope Weighting (default = 1)

Unfortunately, I didn't find much information about them and I am unsure how to decide which ones to use for my site. Both cited publications (Boehner et al 2002 and Boehner & Selige 2006) lack an explanation of these parameters and the SAGA tool itself has hardly any description (see [Link](https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/saga_tool_doc/6.3.0/ta_hydrology_15.html)).

The latter, for example, says that for *Suction* "the lower this value is the stronger is the suction effect" but what is this suction effect and how strong should it be in my area?

References:

- Boehner, J., Koethe, R. Conrad, O., Gross, J., Ringeler, A., Selige, T. (2002): Soil Regionalisation by Means of Terrain Analysis and Process Parameterisation. In: Micheli, E., Nachtergaele, F., Montanarella, L. [Ed.]: Soil Classification 2001. European Soil Bureau, Research Report No. 7, EUR 20398 EN, Luxembourg. pp.213-222. [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170319004518/http://eusoils.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ESDB_Archive/eusoils_docs/esb_rr/EUR22646EN.pdf).
- Boehner, J., Selige, T. (2006): Spatial prediction of soil attributes using terrain analysis and climate regionalisation. In: Boehner, J., McCloy, K.R., Strobl, J. [Eds.]: SAGA - Analysis and Modelling Applications, Goettinger Geographische Abhandlungen, Goettingen: 13-28. [Link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/SAGA%20-%20Documentation/GGA115/gga115_02.pdf/download?use_mirror=altushost-swe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lots of calculations and experiments I think I can (at least partly) answer my own question:

- **Suction**: according to the source code (Conrad 2014), a suction of 10 is "average", a smaller value, e.g. 5 means a higher suction and a higher value, e.g. 15 means a lower suction.
- **Type of Area**:  *total catchment area* is the unaltered version of the area, *root of catchment area* is the square root of the total catchment area and *specific catchment area* is the total catchment area divided by the cell size. *Square root...* leads to lower (drier) results than *total catchment area*.
- **Type of Slope**: *catchment slope* is the unaltered version of the slope, *local slope* causes the slope to be calculated for each cell. *Local slope* gives a more coarse result.
- **Minimum Slope**: all values smaller than this value will be set to this value. A smaller value, e.g. 0, leads to higher WI maximum values.
- **Offset Slope**: is added to each slope value. No apparent influence on maximum values.
- **Slope Weighting**: not sure. In the code, it is used for a power function. `d  = pow(Suction, Slope_Weight * Slope);` but I couldn't make out what influence it has on the results.

I hope this will save someone some time.

Reference:

- Conrad O. (2014): SAGA GIS/ Code/ [4b9c18]/saga-gis/ src/ tools/ terrain_analysis/ ta_hydrology/ SAGA_Wetness_Index.cpp. https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/code/ci/master/tree/saga-gis/src/tools/terrain_analysis/ta_hydrology/SAGA_Wetness_Index.cpp#l301